# Правильно ли передан смысл

Tags: грамотная-речь, смысл

```
Прелестного ребенка заполнилась ниша, 
И звать того, кто в ней, -- Миша!
```

Хочется сказать о нише, предназначенной для прелестного ребенка, которую занял Миша. Правильно ли данное двустишие? Если нет, то по возможности предложите свой вариант.

Comment: Российских поэтов заполнилась ниша // И звать вдохновителя именем Миша!

Comment: А если серьезно, то желательно уточнение подробностей события. Речь идет просто о появлении первенца или до этого все дети были *так себе* и тут наконец-то появился прелестный? Извините, что я иронизирую, но при отсутствии информации об обстоятельствах, Ваше стихотворение может показаться... как бы это сказать... немножко неэтичным.

Comment: Не "заполнилась", а "пополнилась".

Answer (score 2):

Не зная обстоятельств написания данного стихотворения, трудно предложить его улучшенный вариант, поэтому давайте я просто объясню, что плохо в Вашей версии.

Во-первых, "ниша прелестного ребенка" - это звучит не только неэстетично, но еще и двусмысленно. Речь идет о нише **для** прелестного ребенка или о нише **у** прелестного ребенка? Потому что эту строчку можно понять так, что у некого не названного здесь прелестного ребенка была какая-то ниша, и теперь ее заполнил кто-то по имени Миша.

Но даже если идет речь именно о нише **для** прелестного ребенка, то возникает вопрос: для заполнения ниши нужен был именно прелестный? Просто долгожданный не подошел бы? Одно дело, если бы Вы сказали просто о нише, которую заполнил прелестный ребенок по имени Миша, и совсем иначе звучит то, что ниша была именно для прелестного ребенка. А если бы не прелестный родился, тогда бы что? *"This is Sparta!"*, так?

Во-вторых, слова *"звать того, кто в ней"* было бы уместнее сказать, например, о клетке или о яме, но уж никак не о нише.

В-третьих, запятая с двойным тире перед именем Миша - слишком инновационный знак препинания. Обычно в русском языке отдается предпочтение более традиционным схемам пунктуации.